# How to declare two $actsAs variable instances when using multiple plugins in Cake 2.x

Tags: cakephp

Iam using both the 'cakedc search' and 'meioupload' plugins, I currently load them using:

```
CakePlugin::load('MeioUpload');
CakePlugin::load('Search'); //in the bootstrap.php file.
```

I need to be able to make one model use both of these plugins simultaneously, can anyone suggest a way to declare the $actsAs variable twice in the same model, to avoid getting the follwing error in the 'error.log' file:

```
Error: Fatal Error (64): Cannot redeclare Event::$actsAs
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

you can use as many behaviors per model as you want:

```
public $actsAs = array('Behavior1', 'PluginName.Behavior2', ...);
```

I don't quite see what your problem is.